# PostgreSQL group by without aggregate function. Why does it work?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

there is a strange behavior. I know that when using GROUP BY, all columns from SELECT should either be in group by clause, or have aggregate function. 
However, the next code shows something controversial:

```
// id is a primary key
select id, name from user group by name; <-- error because of group by (expected)
select id, name from user group by id; <-- works (unexpected!)
```

What am I missing? Can not find documentation that says about some potential special case for primary key in group by.

Comment: Removed mysql tag. I think Stack Overflow adds the mysql tag by default in response to some keywords.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is covered, but not especially obvious, in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY):

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.

In this case, I'm guessing that `id` is the primary key of the table `user` which would make `name` functionally dependent on `id`.

Comment: oh, that is really interesting. Thank you, Jeremy, for pointing to this section. For some reason, I missed it when reading about group by.

Comment: I wonder, btw, if this is only PostgreSQL or MySQL will also have this case?

Comment: MySQL would do the equivalent of an oneof (...) Aggregation on any columns that are not aggregated - meaning, return a "random" value from the possible values for the column

Comment: A more strict behavior can be enabled in MySQL with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode, but that is not enabled by default

Comment: A pity that postgres doesn't take unique constraints and foreign keys into account for computing functional dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary key can guaranty unicity for the `id` column.

I tried your statement on PostgreSQL 11.6 and 12.1 and I got the same error

```sql
SELECT id, name from unicity group by id;
ERROR:  column "unicity.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT id, name from unicity group by id;
```

> Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: It works, My bad, I forgot to add the primary key:
```sql
alter table unicity add constraint unicity_pk primary key (id);
```