# SQL basic problem when trying to SELECT 4 atributes and use GROUP BY with only 2

Tags: sql, group-by

The issue arises from the use of an aggregate function (COUNT) on one column (ct.Language) and selecting another column (cb.Population) without applying an aggregate function to it or including it in the GROUP BY clause. This violates SQL syntax rules where all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT clause must be included in the GROUP BY clause unless they are being used in an aggregate function. The question is how to include cb.Population in the query's output without violating SQL syntax rules.

Here is the code:

```
DROP VIEW v1;
CREATE VIEW v1 AS 
    SELECT  
        cb.Name AS Nombre_Pais, 
        COUNT(ct.Language) AS Cantidad_Idiomas_Oficiales,
        cb.Population AS Poblacion_Total, 
        SUM(ct.Percentage) AS Porcentaje_Poblacion_Idioma_Oficial 
    FROM  
        country_backup cb  
    JOIN  
        countrylanguage_backup ct ON cb.Code = ct.CountryCode 
    WHERE  
        ct.IsOfficial = 'T' 
    GROUP BY 
        cb.Name, cb.Population
    HAVING  
        COUNT(ct.Language) > 3;
```

I attempted to modify the view `v1` by including the `cb.Population` column in the `SELECT` clause without aggregating it or including it in the `GROUP BY` clause. I expected to provide a solution to the problem by including `cb.Population` in the query's output while adhering to SQL syntax rules. However, this approach is invalid because it violates the rules of SQL syntax, which require all non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause. Therefore, I need to explore alternative approaches to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Use a CTE or inner-query and re-`JOIN` on that.

Comment: Protip: Try to use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` whenever you write a `VIEW` or `FUNCTION` in SQL Server. It'll save you headaches later on.

Comment: Use a dummy aggregates: `min()` or `max()`. A lot of people will also add those columns to the `group by` but I don't recommend that myself.

Comment: @shawnt00 How is that an improvement?

Comment: Use `MAX(cb.Population) AS Poblacion_Total`, then you can remove the Population from the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Ummm, because it's the right answer...

Comment: P.S. This isn't so much as syntax error as a logic error. Some systems have let users get away with unaggregated output but that output was not always reliable nor what standard SQL would require.

Comment: @Dai: Can you provide a source/reference to why this is considered a _hack_, or why this should not be the way to solve this ?

Comment: Well I don't think anybody ever called SQL a serious programming language. I'm kinda confused that you both so riled up while also completely wrong.

Comment: @shawnt00 It's not "let users get away with something" - it's part of the ISO SQL spec for the correct handling of columns with valid functional-dependency mappings to the grouping keys.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't invoke the standard. That probably is in there. Regardless, most platforms require the hoop-jumping.

Comment: @Luuk It's RDMBS dependent: for [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) (and [non-braindead versions of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)) [it's well supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58960000/159145). It's just unfortunate that MSSQL does not currently support it (bah!) but just adjusting the query to use a CTE and self-join solves it in MSSQL land.

Comment: @shawnt00 _"I'm kinda confused that you both so riled up while also completely wrong."_. [Because we're nerds on the Internet](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: I don't understand how a redundant join is any better than just telling it how to just trivially summarize the identical values.

Comment: I remove the tag [tag:basic] because 1) This is not a basic question (see responses from @Dai ), and 2) [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) is a programming language, with no reference to SQL.

Comment: @Dai Arguably you shouldn't ever have a functional dependency which needs aggregating, it implies there is poor normalization somewhere. So yeah it's a design issue.

Comment: @shawnt00 SQL is a serious programming language, it's just not a *generalized multi-purpose* language. It's also designed in the '80s and it shows.

Comment: "The issue arises from ... without applying an aggregate function to it or including it in the GROUP BY clause."  AND "This violates SQL syntax rules where all non-aggregated columns in the SELECT clause must be included in the GROUP BY clause unless they are being used in an aggregate function."  ........ **WHY is the reference to (wherever SQL syntax is defined) missing ?** (please include the place where this statement is _defined_).   Finally **to achieve the desired result.**: why ware they missing from this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I made kind of running example for you, add some dummy data for understanding.
so if you want to remove Population from grouping - you need kind of aggregate values (its one to many) so avg/sum/max/min, etc... depends what you want to see
in this example i made as SUM of populations in countryCode grouping

```
drop table if exists country_backup 
drop table if exists countrylanguage_backup

create Table dbo.country_backup (Name varchar(50), Population int, Code int)
create Table dbo.countrylanguage_backup (CountryCode int, Language varchar(50), Percentage decimal(16,4), IsOfficial char)

insert into dbo.country_backup Values
('name 1', 30, 123),('name 1', 30, 123),('name 3', 10, 123),('name 4', 60, 123)
,('name 1', 30, 123),('name 1', 30, 123),('name 1', 30, 111),('name 1', 30, 123)

insert into dbo.countrylanguage_backup Values
(123, 'English', 5.0, 'T'),(123, 'English', 5.0, 'T'),(123, 'English', 10.0, 'T'),(123, 'English', 2.2, 'T'),(123, 'English', 5.4, 'T')

GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView --WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  
        Nombre_Pais = cb.[Name], 
        Cantidad_Idiomas_Oficiales = COUNT(ct.[Language]),
        --aggregatedPopulatons = STRING_AGG(cb.Population, ','), 
        Poblacion_Total = SUM(cb.Population), 
        Porcentaje_Poblacion_Idioma_Oficial = SUM(ct.[Percentage]) 
    FROM dbo.country_backup cb
    JOIN dbo.countrylanguage_backup ct ON ct.CountryCode = cb.Code 
                                AND ct.IsOfficial = 'T'
    GROUP BY cb.Name--, cb.Population
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
GO

select * from dbo.MyView


drop view dbo.MyView
drop table if exists dbo.country_backup 
drop table if exists dbo.countrylanguage_backup
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle** sintax used:
Since there are no sample data nor expected result it is hard to tell what is this all about.
We can just speculate about it and repeat some basic things about Group By clause and aggregations in SQL.
To do it lets suppose that your sample data could be like this...

```sql
/*  country_backup
CODE  NAME         POPULATION
----  -----------  ----------
 101  Name 101            312
 102  Name 102            274
 103  Name 103            198
 104  Name 104            290
 105  Name 105            312   */
```

```sql
 /*  country_language_backup
COUNTRY_CODE  LANGUAGE  PERCENTAGE  IS_OFFICIAL
------------  --------  ----------  -----------
         101  English         32.5  T
         101  French          12.0  T
         102  English         37.3  T
         102  German          22.5  T
         102  Italian         12.2  T
         103  English         62.5  T
         104  English         21.4  T
         104  German          10.0  T
         105  English         72.5  T           */
```

The **result of Group By** clause **is 1 row per column(s) listed** in the clause.

```sql
Select   LANGUAGE 
From     country_language_backup 
Group By LANGUAGE
```

```sql
/*  Result:
LANGUAGE
--------
German
English
French
Italian     */
```

...  or - with the data from both tables  ...

```sql
Select   cb.NAME, ct.LANGUAGE 
From     country_backup cb
Inner Join country_language_backup ct ON( cb.CODE = ct.COUNTRY_CODE )
Where    cb.CODE = 102
Group By cb.NAME, ct.LANGUAGE
Order By cb.NAME, ct.LANGUAGE
```

```sql
/*  R e s u l t :
NAME     LANGUAGE
-------- --------
Name 102 English
Name 102 German 
Name 102 Italian   */
```

If there is no LANGUAGE in Group By clause - the query will try to fetch 1 row for 102, 'Name 102' as CODE and NAME.
If you don't aggregate LANGUAGE column then the engine could not know which of three values to fetch with that one CODE, NAME row.
You aggregated the LANGUAGE column with Count() and there are no problems.

```sql
Select   cb.NAME, Count(ct.LANGUAGE) "CANTIDAD_IDIOMAS_OFICIALES" 
From     country_backup cb
Inner Join country_language_backup ct ON( cb.CODE = ct.COUNTRY_CODE )
Where    cb.CODE = 102
Group By cb.NAME
Order By cb.NAME
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
NAME     CANTIDAD_IDIOMAS_OFICIALES
-------- --------------------------
Name 102                          3 */
```

Now about POPULATION column - if your data is like my sample data from above (table country_backup where 1 CODE has 1 POPULATION value) then there is no reason not to include POPULATION column in Group By list.
If CODE column values in table country_backup are not unique you should aggregate POPULATION column.
So, your query (with the above sample data) may stay just as it is...

```sql
Select      cb.NAME "NOMBRE_PAIS", 
            Count(ct.LANGUAGE) "CANTIDAD_IDIOMAS_OFICIALES",
            cb.POPULATION "POBLACION_TOTAL", 
            Sum(ct.PERCENTAGE) "PORCENTAJE_POBLACION_IDIOMA_OFICIAL" 
From        country_backup cb  
Inner Join  country_language_backup ct ON( cb.CODE = ct.COUNTRY_CODE )
Where       ct.IS_OFFICIAL = 'T' 
Group BY    cb.NAME, cb.POPULATION
Having      Count(ct.LANGUAGE) > 2;
```

...

```sql
/*  R e s u l t :  
NOMBRE_PAIS CANTIDAD_IDIOMAS_OFICIALES POBLACION_TOTAL PORCENTAJE_POBLACION_IDIOMA_OFICIAL
----------- -------------------------- --------------- -----------------------------------
Name 102                             3             274                                  72  */
```